# Flask-SQLAlchemy & JINJA 2 - Why is this not working?

Tags: flask

I am running a Flask app with flask_SQLAlchemy and a SQLITE Database. I am trying to retrieve all doctor names and place them onto a HTML page where users have the option to select what doctor they want.

Comment: if you have `for doctors in ...` then you should use the same name in `doctors.doctor_name`but you use wrong `Doctors.doctor_name`. Maybe better use names which more different ie. `for doctor in all_doctors:` First is `singular` `doctor`, and second is plural `doctors` with extrad prefix `all_` to make name more different.

Comment: now I see you mess with these names - you send `doctors=Doctors` so in jinja you have access only to `doctors` with lower case `d` but you use `Doctors` with upper case `D`

Comment: other problem - if you ger data from database then you have to assign to variable and later use this variable to send to jinja - but you run `Doctors.query.filter_by(Doctors.doctor_name).all()` without assigning to variable and later you send totally different `Doctors`

Answer (score 1):

You mess with variables - you have `Doctors` and `doctors` and you simply use wrong variables in wrong places.

I will use different names to show which variables you should use in Flask and which in `Jinja`

First: if you get values from database then you have to assign to variable

```
selected_doctors = Doctors.query.filter_by(Doctors.doctor_name).all()
```

and later send this variable `selected_doctors` to `Jinja`

```
return render_template(..., all_doctors=selected_doctors)
```

Specially I use `all_doctors` to make it more visible which variable you should use later in Jinja

And in Jinja you should use `all_doctors` but you use `Doctors` which you don't sent to Jinja

```
{% for one_doctor in all_doctors %}

<option value="{{ one_doctor.id }}"> {{ one_doctor.doctor_name }} </option>

{% endfor %}
```

Because `for` gets single element from list `all_doctors` so you could  use singular `one_doctor` (or shorter `doctor`) instead plural `doctors`.

---

**EDIT**

Here how it could look.

And first you could use `print(selected_doctors)` to check if you get anything from database. If variable is empty then you get empty list in HTML.

```
selected_doctors = Doctors.query.filter_by(Doctors.doctor_name).all()

print(selected_doctors)  # <--- check what you get

return render_template('appointment.html',
                       name=current_user.email,
                       all_doctors=selected_doctors)
```

```
<div class="col-12">
    <select name="doctor_name" class="form-select">
        <option selected> Select Preferred Doctor</option>
        {% for one_doctor in all_doctors %}
        <option value="example">{{ one_doctor.doctor_name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I have configured everything to similar to the one you've given me and the HTML page drop down menu is just literally blank. I have been trying to figure this out for 2 days now, confused 

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to check what you get from database - maybe you get nothing and this is problem.

Comment: When I used print and run the file, I get the  'from .models import db
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package'.

Comment: so you have problem in different place. You should create new question on new page and show code and FULL error message.

Comment: Which I have  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71637089/variable-returning-non-iterable-object-for-some-reason

Comment: I managed to finally print the selected doctors without getting import errors BUT Pycharm shows me 'Process finished with exit code 0' and nothing else indicating that the variable line is wrong maybe

Comment: run directly in console/terminal without PyCharm to see if code works.